# Import account from Windows Live Mail to Outlook 2013

Tags: windows-live-mail, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is it possible to import emails and settings from Windows Live Mail to Outlook 2013?

The accounts I would like to import are POP3 accounts like Gmail and my ISP.

Answer (score 2):

### Exporting Calendar from Windows Live Mail to Microsoft Outlook 2013

1. Open Windows Live Mail.
2. Select the Calendar folder and make sure that you are logged in by using your Windows Live ID.
3. Click the Share and select your Windows Live account, if you have an Outlook account, it will also be displayed.
4. You will be given the option to share or not to share the calendar, select Share this calendar and click Save.
5. Place a check mark in Send people a view-only link to your calendar and click Save.
6. Click Get your calendar links (This will also save your settings) and click OK in the warning window that opens.
7. The grayed out links will now be usable, click on the link that best describes how much or how little calendar information you want to share.
8. A window will open with a link that you can email to those people who you want to be able to view your calendar or import your calendar data.

### Exporting Contacts from Windows Live Mail to Microsoft Outlook 2013

1. Open Windows Live Mail.
2. Click Contacts folder, and then click Export.
3. Select Comma separated values (.CSV).
4. In the CSV Export window click Browse and select the Desktop folder.
5. Type WLMContacts in the file name and then click the Save button.
6. Click Next and select all the fields that you want to export, click Finish button and wait for the export process to be completed.

   > **Note**: The most common fields are First Name, Last Name, Email address and Telephone. If you are not sure about the information just select all the fields.
   >
   > **Note**: This process can take some time, depending on the number of messages that you are exporting.
7. Close Windows Live Mail.
8. Open Excel, select File, and then click Open.
9. Select the Desktop folder, and choose to show All Files.
10. Select and open the WLMContacts.csv file that you created in step 5.
11. Select File, and then click Save As.
12. In the Save As dialog, change Save as type: to CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), and then click Save.
13. Click Yes if asked to replace or overwrite the existing file.
14. Click Yes if asked to keep the CSV format.
15. Close Excel.
16. Open Outlook, select Contacts and click File.
17. Select Open & Export and click Import/Export.
18. In the window that opens, select Import from another program or file and click Next.
19. Highlight Comma Separated Values and click Next.
20. Click the Browse button and select the Desktop folder.
21. Select the file WLMContacts.csv, and then click OK.

    > **Note**: You can select some additional options to replace, duplicate, or do not import duplicated contacts.
22. In the next window highlight your Contacts folder and click Next.
23. Click Finish in the window that opens.

**Important:** Exporting Windows Live Mail or Outlook Express mail to Outlook 2013 requires that Outlook 2013 be 32bit. For more information, please refer to: [Issues moving Internet Mail and Addresses to Outlook 2013 (64 bit)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2796528).

[Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980534)

Comment: If somebody can figure out how to fix the ordering of the list I would apprecaite it. For some reason it wants to restart because of quoted statements.

Comment: This is the best I could do. The markup for lists is really irritating, and I don't know why it's inserting an unnecessary blank line after #7 and #22.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but what about the emails?

Comment: There are numerous programs that exist that will help you do that.  Impossible for me to update the question since Windows Live Mail is no longer available